# Not sure if this is possible, but I would like to position a bar at the bottom of the view port, which stays until the footer scrolls into view

Tags: bootstrap-4, css-position

Hoping i can explain this clearly. I searched for many permutations and can't find anything that pertains...

I have a bar, with some buttons, that "sticks" to the bottom of the view port using absolute, and fixed, positioning. This I understand (using bootstrap 4).

What I would like to then happen is when the user scrolls the page, and the footer then comes into view, the button bar would then move up with the footer so as not to obscure the footer. When the user then scrolls the page down and the footer moves out of view, the button bar would then stay at the bottom of the view port.

How might I approach this? I've tried a bunch of things but can't seem to get it latch onto the footer.

Thanks for all the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

you would probably want to try the jQuery scroll function: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

so you can detect the scroll distance where the button bar is, then change the css to make the viewport bar unfixed. May be a bit tricky though.

Comment: Interesting. I'll give it a look. Thanks.